# Get working tree from private git repository

Tags: git, github, github-api

Basically this example works on non private repositories:

`https://api.github.com/repos/<user>/<repository-name>/git/trees/<branch-name>?recursive=1`

Wanting to get it to work on private repository, could be not in the bowser, terminal is also an option.

Comment: Surely this would undermine the point of the repo being private?

Comment: Well sure, but if i can clone the repository, then maybe with the help of a command, if such exists

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos has more information about what you can get from repos (private as well!). Working tree probably isn't one as that requires a commit to be checked out which can't happen with bare repos.

Comment: Are you looking for the `git ls-tree` command ? Possibly `git ls-tree -r` ?

Comment: yep it ended something like this `git ls-tree HEAD -r`